# Cron Job for call a PHP program

Tags: php, bash, cron

I need a create a cron job to call a PHP program, when I will call a PHP program ,I need to send a date parameter as well.

The below code working fine in the linux terminal.

```
php execute_attendance.php 10/12/2022.
```

I have created cron job but it's not running.....

```
*/15 * * * * unb /opt/unb/bin/execute_attendance date +%F --date="15 days ago"> /dev/null 2>&1
```

`date +%F --date="15 days ago"` this code is returning sysdate - 15,it working fine with linux terminal.

Comment: This is a computer question instead of a programming question, but basically you're passing in the literal `date +%F --date="15 days ago"` instead of having it evaluated. You should be able to surround it with `$()` in order to get it to evaluate the value, though I've never tried it in a cron file. `$(date +%F --date="15 days ago")`

Comment: What's `unb` in the cron entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap this into bash script like:

```
#! /bin/bash
d=$(date +%F --date="15 days ago")
php execute_attendance.php "$d"
```

and after this add bash script call to cron

```
*/15 * * * * unb your_bash_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

another way is move date calculation within php script

Comment: `#! /bin/bash` makes no sense for cron jobs since it uses `sh` and shebang is only useful for executable scripts. `d=$(date +%F --date="15 days ago")` is better than backtick obsolete since 35 years ago syntax. No need for upper case variable name. `php execute_attendance.php "$d"` always quote variable expansion. Transmitting knowledge is better if you can also transmit good and up-to date practices. There are enough rotten tech text books all around teaching obsolete syntaxes and deprecated practices.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Updated my answer following your instructions